# Prevent cursor appearance switching in macOS

Tags: macos, cursor

When using macOS, the cursor appearance will change very often. For instance, it will switch from an arrow to a hand when you hover over a link in Safari. It will also get updated when you hover over the edge of a window to indicate that resizing mode can be activated, etc.

My desire would be to suppress this behaviour and have the cursor always be the standard arrow and never change.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm hoping this can fix a bad bug that occurs when using macOS with a screen that has a resolution of 5120x2880

Comment: Your comment makes me suspect this might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why not ask about the bug itself, (possibly mentioning this as an idea of a workaround) rather than jumping straight to the workaround?

Comment: You are right, I will probably post a separate question concerning this bug specifically. I'm still trying to understand what triggers it and its effects. This would be a step towards diagnostic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mousecape](https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape) to apply custom cursors on macOS. For your use case you would have to create a custom cursors file ('cape') where the cursors of all types are identical.

Comment: Of course, technically it would still change, though all images would be *equivalent*. So it might not do anything about whatever bug the OP is encountering.